# Spring Data Rest support for couchbase?

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest, spring-data-couchbase

I am finding trouble figuring out if Spring Data Rest is planning to gain support for Spring Data Couchbase.  It doesn't look like there is support yet.  Is there someway I can confirm if anyone is working on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Data Supports couchbase: http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-couchbase/

And Spring Data Rest supports and Spring data layer so you are good to go!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had time to look into Spring Data REST + Spring Data Couchbase yet... That said, Spring Data REST should work with the Spring Data generic abstraction, shouldn't it?

Maybe some specificities of the Couchbase store implementation make it difficult to work with Spring Data REST? Did you hit particular roadblocks? In which case any feedback and contribution (in the form of either a well-documented [jira ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACOUCH/) or even a [pull-request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-couchbase/)) would be of course appreciated ;)